# Using pygame key.name to convert keys to str. How to convert it to pygame key?

Tags: python, pygame

In order to build controller setting i want convert key pressed to string.

for that i built a setting controller class:

```
class KeyboardSettings():
    def __init__(self,description,keyboard,rect):
        self.description = description
        self.keyboard = keyboard
        self.active = False
        self.default = keyboard
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
        
    def active_key(self):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        
        if self.rect.collidepoint((pos)) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                self.active = True   
        elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            self.active = False
```

All game keys are added to key_obj_lst and In game loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == dict_key:
        for k in SETTINGS.key_obj_lst:
            # define each key by user
            if k.active:
               k.keyboard = pygame.key.name(event.key)
                        SETTINGS.default = False
```

Now i able to get the key as a string but i wounder if it possible to convert it to pygame.event.key?

Answer (score 1):

it's good or you can do

```
    while True:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    moving_left = True
```